# How do I merge from master into project, discarding all project commits?

Tags: git

I have (or am aiming to have!) a repo like so:

```
Master *-----*--*----------C---
        \                   \
Project1 \-*-------A----B----M2---A'--B'---
          \              \             \
Project2   \----------*---M1------------M2---
```

I would like to do the merge **M2** but I would like **A** and **B** to be **completely** ignored. I will then manually (e.g. cherry-pick) recreate **A'** and **B'** as/if necessary atop the new changes from the master.

Project2 is based on the Master, but merges in changes from Project1.

Desired outcome:

1. I want point **M2** to be an identical copy of **C** in terms of files.
2. I need Project1 to have its own linear history so that Project2 can merge from it.

Context: Master is Drupal's main codebase. Project1 is a branch I use to maintain specific patches that I wish to share with several projects. Project2 (and many others) merge from Project1.

I have considered:

1. `git merge -s recursive -X theirs master` problem with this is that AFAIK it will only prefer `theirs` if something conflicts. So if a change in A does not conflict, it will be present at **M2** which will mean that A' will be incomplete.
2. `git revert B..A ; git merge C` This will work but will leave me with a messy and long history.
3. There is `git merge -s ours` but there does not seem to be a `git merge -s theirs`.
4. I do not want to `git reset --hard C` because this will (I think) break the possibility of merging Project1 into Project2. Another approach would be to rebase Project1 onto C, but again, this would mean I could not merge into Project2.

Comment: If you want "an identical copy of C", why dont you just delete your Project2 folder, and `git clone <Master URL>; git checkout C` ?

Comment: I want the tree at the tip of branch Project1 to be identical to that at C. I don't want to copy any files into a new repo (which is what clone does). The question is about bringing the state of the tree in the project1 branch up to the same point as a given commit in the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the "plumbing" commands:

```
$ git checkout Project1
$ git diff HEAD..master | patch -p1 
$ git add -A .
$ git commit-tree `git write-tree` -p master -p Project1 \
      -m "Merge to clean Master at v1.2"
0c5290081989cc28ff3977fbfe3951db7b7778b0
$ git reset --hard 0c5290081989cc28ff3977fbfe3951db7b7778b0
```

The `git diff HEAD..master` will tell me how to get from where I'm at (**B**) and where I want to be (**C**) in one big patch, and patch will, of course, apply it.

`git add -A .` will add all the changes in the working tree into the index.

We then create a merge commit for this with the next line: the `git-write-tree` creates a new tree object from the index, and outputs its SHA1 as an argument to `git commit-tree`, which creates a commit for it having two parents, the current heads of Project1 (**B**) and master (**C**), and give it a suitable message.

Git will create the commit object, but it won't update any branches to use this commit. The final line tells git that we want our current branch, Project2, to be advanced (fast forwarded) to the commit SHA1 it generated.

From there you can recreate (e.g. might try with cherry-pick) the patches A' and B', if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice against your plans – you are trying to fool git. Git does not like to be fooled. Also you are “faking” your history. M2, A’ and B’ should all be one commit – the merge.

But if you want to go ahead, do this:

```
git merge --no-commit C
rm -rf *
git checkout C .
git commit
```

If you have any gitignored files that you want to keep, back them up before the `rm` and restore them afterwards.

Alternatively, you can also do (actually a lot cleaner)

```
git checkout C
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/Project1
git update-ref MERGE_HEAD C
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer(s). I don't think I'm fooling git (it is, by its own [definition](http://code.google.com/p/git-core/), stupid). I am instructing it about the correct way (as determined by me) to merge, just like I would if it came across a conflict. Your first answer works a charm (tried 3rd but ended with detached head). I've posted another answer which I think avoids problems with .gitignored files and spares the rather scary `rm -rf *`.

Comment: Git does indeed not care about a lot of things. But git wants it’s history to be truth. Adding fake merges often causes trouble. A merge commit is supposed to contain all the changes from two branches – Yours does not.